# Why are new questions not showing up on the front page?

Tags: bug, questions

Oftentimes, when I see a chat message from @NewPosts, I can't get to the same post from the home page. What's up with that?

Comment: Dumb question but are you sure the ones that're doing that aren't meta posts? It's the same bot that posts them.

Comment: Yeah, usually they show up if I wait 5-10 minutes.

Comment: It's probably just caching

Comment: shouldiblamecaching.com

Answer (score 2):

It takes a minute. This isn’t a bug and is universal. It will also take 1 minute for edited posts to be bumped up.